# How to filter cookies when you send ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, cookies

If you send ajax request to a server and your size of cookies is too large, you get the message:

> Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>   Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.
>
> Cookie

Is there any way to filter cookies via javascript (jQuery, Angular) before sending request? For example: I have 25kb of cookies on the certain website (limit on the server is 16kb), there is a session cookie among them. How I can send only session cookie to the server or the cookies which I want? Is this possible without deleting redundant cookies?

Another example:
 I have domain cookies `.mysite.com`. If i go to `one.mysite.com` I get another cookies, when I go to `two.mysite.com` new cookies are installed and etc. When I send ajax request from one of those sites cookies are summarizing and they all goes to Header of request which may exceed server limit.

I have a lot of cookies, but no one is exceeds 3kb. The main question is : Can I filter cookies in JavaScript by domain name?

Comment: I'm kind of confused... if the cookie is too large for your server (note that cookies are stored on the client where the limit is 4k), this should be an issue not just within an ajax request but any http request. please provide more info. why is your cookie more than 4k (the size limit of your standard cookie)?

Comment: @jeremy I have domain cookies `.mysite.com`. If i go to `one.mysite.com` I get another cookies, when I go to `two.mysite.com` new cookies are installed and etc. When I send ajax request from one of those sites cookies are summarizing and they all goes to Header of request which may exceed server limit.

Comment: Yeah very confusing. How many cookies are you generating pre domain? Are there cookies that exceed more than 4k? You can always call one cookie at a time, but if too large then you are storing way to much in one cookie. Might want to rethink your code.

Comment: @CesarBielich I have a lot of cookies, but no one is exceeds 3kb. The main question is : Can I filter cookies  in JavaScript by domain name?

Comment: simply, no. cookies are stored on the client and provide stateful information for http requests. you are likely doing something wrong. rethink, refactor, recode...

Answer (score 0):

Just set the domain and path attributes on your cookie, like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cookieName = 'HelloWorld';
var cookieValue = 'HelloWorld';
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 12);
document.cookie = cookieName +"=" + cookieValue + ";expires=" + myDate + ";domain=.example.com;path=/";
</script>
```

Then you can call a cookie by it's domain value.

Comment: It Ok, but when I send ajax request from the page, all cookies from the page goes to  Header request. Is there any chance to send certain cookies?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing and it looks like browsers hide this kind of access to users. I imagine is probably for security reasons. The maximum we could do is to [specify the credentials config](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials#value) in the fetch to `omit`, `same-origin`, or `include`. I didn't find anything in [the spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265#section-6.1).

Another option would be to use a custom HTTP Header, instead of a cookie.

[This may be helpful.](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/349#issuecomment-225677823)